# Cant resolve instance with Unity container

Tags: c#, unity-container

I register an instance with Unity like this:

```
ContentSlideControlsEntity contentSlideControlsEntity = new ContentSlideControlsEntity(new Queue<uint>());
        container.RegisterInstance(typeof(ContentSlideControlsEntity), "contentSlideControlsEntity", contentSlideControlsEntity);
```

And then I simply want to reslove it:

```
ContentSlideControlsEntity contentSlideControlsEntity2 = container.Resolve<ContentSlideControlsEntity>();
```

but I get the following runtime error:

> Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: 'Resolution of
>   the dependency failed, type =
>   "MSDataLayer.Entities.ContentSlideControlsEntity", name = "(none)".
>
> Exception occurred while: while resolving.
>
> Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type Queue`1 has
>   multiple constructors of length 1. Unable to disambiguate.
>
> ---
>
> At the time of the exception, the container was:
>
> Resolving MSDataLayer.Entities.ContentSlideControlsEntity,(none)
>
> Resolving parameter "slideIDQueue" of constructor
>   MSDataLayer.Entities.ContentSlideControlsEntity(System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1[[System.UInt32,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] slideIDQueue)
>
> ```
> Resolving System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1[System.UInt32],(none)
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You registered your instance as a named registration, but you are resolving the unnamed registration (which doesn't exist).

```
container.RegisterInstance(typeof(ContentSlideControlsEntity), "contentSlideControlsEntity", contentSlideControlsEntity);
                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You have 2 options:

1) Don't register it as a named registraion

```
container.RegisterInstance(typeof(ContentSlideControlsEntity), contentSlideControlsEntity);
```

2) Resolve it with a name

```
container.Resolve<ContentSlideControlsEntity>("contentSlideControlsEntity");
```